# Filtering TypeScript array with two types to just one type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the [snoowrap Reddit API wrapper](https://not-an-aardvark.github.io/snoowrap/) to get a list of reported Comment objects from a subreddit. The `getReports` method returns an array of type `Submission | Comment`, but you can pass a parameter in to it to get only Comments in the returned data.

However it still comes back as an array with both types, so I wanted to use a filter to only keep the ones that are Comment type. This only modifies the items, and doesn't change the type of the array to just Comments.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
getReportedComments(): Comment[] {
    return this.r
        .getSubreddit("subreddit")
        .getReports({ only: "comments" }) // returns a Listing<Submission|Comment>, which is just a subclass of Array
        .filter(comment => comment instanceof Comment)
}
```

`r` is a Snoowrap object.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "still comes back as an array with both types", do you mean that the return type still includes both types, or that at runtime the request actually comes back populated with both types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that there is only comments, you can cast it to the type you want.

```
getReportedComments(): Comment[] {
    return this.r
        .getSubreddit("subreddit")
        .getReports({ only: "comments" }) as Comment[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the type-def could probably be improved to use an overload:

```
  getReports(options?: ListingOptions & { only?: 'links' }): Listing<Submission | Comment>;
  getReports(options?: ListingOptions & { only: 'comments' }): Listing<Comment>;


const reports = r.getReports(); // reports is Listing<Submission | Comment>

const comments = r.getReports({ only: "comments" }); // comments is Listing<Comment>
```